# Difficulty adding widget to django project

Tags: django

Firstly I apologize for the very basic question but I am currently learning to develop and have read a lot of documentation and searched a lot but still cannot get this working.

I'm building a website using Django framework am trying to add the [django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/) widget. I am having a lot of difficulty figuring out exactly where the different parts of code should go. I have included snippets from my model.py and forms.py files below. The forms work as they are now, but I encounter lots of problems when I try to add the datePicker widget.

I have added the appropriate files to INSTALLED_APPS.

```
class PersonalInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    GENDERS = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDERS)
    dob = models.DateTimeField(datetime.datetime.now())
```

```
class PersonalInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonalInformation

        # i know this bit is wrong but cannot fix it
        dob = forms.DateField(widget=DatePickerInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'))
        
        fields = ['first_name', 'surname', 'gender', 'dob']
```

It runs, but the dob field just displays the timestamp that was saved upon user creation (I don't actually want to save a date at all until the user enters one, but I must set a default otherwise it wont migrate) and doesn't display the widget.

Thank you very much and I apologize for the very basic question but I have spent hours trying to figure it out and am just going around in circles.

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck at? What type of errors are you getting? First off, you need a date or time field to use the datepicker, and I don't see any in your Model or your form.

Comment: @EdgardoObregón Sorry, I edited my code and added it

Answer (score 0):

1) you can set null True in your Date field, and default None, this way won't get a default now() every time you save a new instance.

```
dob = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
```

2) In your form, to override the default field widget the way you tried to, you have to do it outside the Meta class:

```
class PersonalInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):

   dob = forms.DateField(widget=DatePickerInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'))
   class Meta:
      model = PersonalInformation
      fields = ['first_name', 'surname', 'gender', 'dob']
```

Or with the widget attribute within the Meta class:

```
class PersonalInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):

      class Meta:
         model = PersonalInformation
         fields = ['first_name', 'surname', 'gender', 'dob']
         widgets = {
            'dob': DatePickerInput(format='%m/%d/%Y')
         }
```